# SQL Server 2016 - Developing in developer edition - production in Standard edition

Tags: sql-server

I am designing a new environment.  Our production load/requirements dictates using SQL Server Standard edition.  I am wanting to setup our Dev and Test environments with Developer Edition(DE).  As DE is a fully functional Enterprise version, are there any features that would be inherently used that would cause any issues when moved to standard or do all of the feature differences need to be "turned on" in order to use them?

Comment: The MS site has a [feature matrix for the SQL Server editions](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2017-editions) that compares them.

Comment: All features except the availability features are available even in SQL Server Express. Availability features means online index rebuilding, online restores etc.  Some encryption features like TDS are only available in Enterprise.  Even partitioning is available in Express. Developer edition is equivalent to Enterprise. All of this is documented

Comment: The [Editions and supported features of SQL Server 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-2017) shows what features are available in each editions. There are equivalent pages in the docs for previous versions as well.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I have been reviewing these for a while now and am fairly comfortable with the edition differences.  what I am trying to determine is if our team would inadvertently take advantage of an Enterprise feature that would break once we published to Standard.

Comment: Yes - it is possible that your team does, in fact, do that. Not likely given the edition differences, but possible.